# Topologically distinct Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, topology

Are these two diagrams topologically distinct?

[image]

I consider $\phi^4$ theory and use the minimal subtraction renormalization scheme. A vertex corresponding to counterterm $-\imath \frac{m^2 \lambda}{32 \pi^2 \epsilon}$  is denoted by cross and $-\imath \lambda$ vertex is denoted by bold point.

Comment: I would say it is the same diagram. The second is obtained from the first by a "rotation" of the loops. But this "rotation" is only inverting the momenta  of the loops, while you have to sum to all loops momenta to get the Feynmann diagram. Now you may write explicitely the value of the Feynmann diagrams to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think these diagrams could correspond to different contributions. Trimok already posted an explanation in the comments, but I think there is an even simpler way to see that the diagrams must be the same: If you write out the expression corresponding to them, the only difference will be the 'placement' of the counterterm factor. However, this is just a number and therefore its placement makes no difference: The expressions must be the same.